# wpf- Unwanted Selection Change

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

in my Main Tab,I have some controls,
in my first control I have a Combobox.
I wrote an SelectionChange for MainTab , 
but it also fires when it accoured in combobox,I hadnt add any selection change event to my combobox,
but when I add selection change to Combobox and set e.erouted=true , the maintab selection changed will not be fired.
what Can I do to prevent firing maintab selectionchange when I change another control selected item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Main tab selection change event

```
 if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() != typeof(ComboBox))
     {
         //do the code of main tab selection  here..

     }
```

Comment: Thanks dear shebin.Its better Idea to use original source.

Comment: And if you embed an object other than a ComboBox, example another TabControl? You're best to compare instances versus type.

Answer (score 1):

I have hit this problem as well, and have not yet found the cause or correct solution. My current (albeit simple) workaround for this is to check that the sender is the object you are expecting.

In this case it would mean something like this:

```
if (sender != MainTab) 
    return;
```

Comment: Thanks fatty,But I want to do sth that It will not fire.

Answer (score -1):

Setting e.Handled to true will stop the event from bubbling up from child control (ComboBox) to the parent control (TabControl)

Comment: its problem is that event should be added to every Combobox,which we can't add to all of them.(we don't want)